# Erro ao submeter um form. Campo do tipo "select" não está sendo enviado. A tag <form> fecha sozinha, antes do fim do formulario

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Ao submeter um "form" com php, o "option" do meu "select" não está sendo enviado. Tentei via GET e via POST e não obtive sucesso. Verifiquei no inspecionar e a tag "form" está fechando sozinha, antes do "select", só que no meu código ela fecha bem depois.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue código que contém o form.

```html
<form action="painel_gerentes.php" method="POST">
                                
  <input type="hidden" name="c_operacao" value="alterar_gerente">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_clicado" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <br/>

  <div class="row">       

    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="nme_rec" type="text" class="validate" name="c_nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" required>
        <label for="nme_rec">Nome:</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="email_ger" type="email" class="validate" name="c_email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
        <label for="email_ger">Email:</label>
      </div>
    </div>

      <?php 

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM loja LIMIT 4";
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $res = $stmt->get_result();

      ?>
      <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="input-field">
          <select name="c_loja">
            <option value="<?php echo $loja; ?>" disabled selected>Loja 0<?php echo $loja; ?></option>

            <?php 
              while ($r = $res->fetch_array() ) {
                $id_loja = $r["id"];
                $nome_loja = $r["nome"];
                
                echo '<option value="' . $id_loja . '">' . $nome_loja . '</option>';
                
              }
            ?>

          </select>
          <label>Loja</label>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 center">
      <?php include("inc/botoes_cadastro.php"); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: SEGUE PRINT DE COMO ESTA O CODIGO NO INSPECIONAR]

Assim fica o meu código quando inspecionado. A tag form fecha sozinha

Comment: Retire os códigos PHP e veja novamente no inspecionar.

Comment: Já retirei, e continua do mesmo jeito. Troquei por radio button e funcionou, mas eu preferia usar select.